# Problem extracting XML response after sending XML via PHP curl

Tags: php, xml, curl

I'm having some problems with my following code:

```
<?php
$url = "192.168.0.1:10040";

$xml = '<root><list><MatrixConnectionList><DviConsole type="name">Monitor X</DviConsole></MatrixConnectionList></list></root>';

$headers = array(
    "Content-type: text/xml",
    "Content-length: " . strlen($xml),
    "Connection: close",
);


//Execute the curl init
$ch = curl_init();

//Add URL to Curl
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

//Return response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//set timeout
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);

//Add post option to curl
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

//Add curel post field
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);

//Add headers
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

//Add verbose for error logging
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

//Execute Curl
$data = curl_exec($ch);

//Print response
error_log(print_r($xml, TRUE));
error_log(print_r($data, TRUE));

//Log errors and close curl
if(curl_errno($ch))
    print curl_error($ch);
else
    curl_close($ch);
?>
```

The reponse should be something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><root><result type="list"><MatrixConnectionList><item><cpuId>0x0000</cpuId><cpuCl>DviCpu</cpuCl><cpuName>MISC</cpuName><cpuPoweredOn>true</cpuPoweredOn><signalType>viewonly</signalType><consoleId>0x000000</consoleId><consoleCl>DviConsole</consoleCl><consoleName>Monitor X</consoleName><connectionOwnerId>0x00000000</connectionOwnerId><connectionOwnerCl>DviMatrix</connectionOwnerCl><connectionOwnerPort>2</connectionOwnerPort><connectionOwnerName>Matrix X</connectionOwnerName><consoleConfigEnable>1</consoleConfigEnable><consolePoweredOn>true</consolePoweredOn><userName>0000000</userName><transmission>2</transmission></item></MatrixConnectionList></result></root>
```

Except when I check my Apache error log I see the following:

```
* upload completely sent off: 118 out of 118 bytes
* Operation timed out after 5001 milliseconds with 1456 out of -1 bytes received
[Thu Apr 30 10:48:05.967278 2020] [php7:notice] [pid 20251] [client 192.168.0.2:6000] , referer: http://192.168.0.1/pages/test.php
```

Am I missing something here? Why isn't curl_exec assigning the returned string to my variable.

Thanks!

Comment: _“Operation timed out after 5001 milliseconds with 1456 out of -1 bytes received”_ - sounds like your remote endpoint is not responding to the request properly? The -1 probably indicates it did not send a Content-Length header, and if it does not close the connection either, then cURL has no way of knowing, when it is supposed to have received _all_ the data.

Comment: @CBroe Thanks! I hadn't thought about it yet. Seems like the endpoint isn't closing it's response and the $data variable never gets filled then.

Answer (score 0):

the server you're hitting isn't sending a `Content-Length` header (either not sending one at all, or sending a malformed one, i'm not sure, you can check the verbose log to find out), which makes curl just keep reading until the remote server close the socket, and the server used more than 5 seconds to close the socket, and 5 seconds seems to be your default CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, so you got a timeout error.. and when you get an error with CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, curl_exec() does not return the response string, but return bool(false) to indicate an error occurred.

you can try to increase CURLOPT_TIMEOUT to see if the server will close the socket eventually,

```
// timeout at 10 seconds instead of 5, server reponds slowly sometimes..
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);
```

or you can remove

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

and add

```
$response="";
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION,function($ch,string $data)use(&$response):int{
    $response.=$data;
    return strlen($data);
});
$error_if_false=curl_exec($ch);
if(false===$error_if_false){
     // error, but your response is now in $response regardless.
}
```